# Edge being hidden by face

Tags: edit-mode, faces, edges

Accidentally deleted an edge, then I added an edge loop. But the face hides the edge. How can I get rid of this? Will only show if I drag x axis smaller.

[image: Edge Hidden by Face]

Comment: Use this link to send the file for analysis: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: z puts the view into wireframe mode.